# Does data-block-on-consent="_till_responded" only work on amp components?

Tags: html, attributes, amp-html

I tried applying `data-block-on-consent="_till_responded"` to regular HTML tags, like `<div>` but that didn't work.

I read through [AMP consent documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-consent/#basic-blocking-behaviors) but couldn't find any clear indicators. Is the use restricted to AMP components only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-*` [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) have no special meaning in HTML & do nothing by default. They are used just to store some custom information.

In order to make it work like in AMP you'll need to develop your own implementation of this functionality using JS.

Since AMP is open source, [you may even check how this functionality is implemented in AMP](https://github.com/ampproject).

Comment: Now that you say it, it makes perfect sense.